# Set background image for a master page that use in sub directories

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, master-pages

I have a master page in my web site root.I have a folder named `Images` in root that Contains a background image for my master page.When I use this master page for my root web pages every thing is OK. But when I use this master page in web pages placed in sub directories because it can not find back ground image,ground image does not show.I don't want to use `MapPath` and get absolute path of image.

How I can show background image every where my master page use.

thanks

Comment: Can you please, Paste code here....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to your images with prefixing slash in your CSS style:

```
body
{
     background-image:url('/images/background.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In master page page load event  set the source attribute of image in  the given format

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  backgroungimageId.src=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Images/xyz.jpg"); 
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: the 'subdirectories' problem is circumvented with the ~ sign at the root of the path. On IIS/ASP this means "the root of the application" and is thus subdir-safe way to refer to global resources.